# Principal root of 3+4i

Tags: complex-numbers

Is there a neat way of writing the principal root of 3+4i? I have an answer, but it is very ugly. Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by principle root?

Comment: Further, I think it would be helpful if you mentioned what your current answer is and why you think it's ugly

Comment: *Principal*. ${}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$(2+i)^2=4-1+4i=3+4i$

You can show it by $(a+ib)^2=3+4i\implies a^2-b^2=3,2ab=4$

Polar form : $\sqrt 5 e^{i\arctan(1/2)}$

Comment: Ok, but only assuming the question is about the *square root*. AFAICT the OP didn't specify :-)

Answer (score 0):

$3+ 4i= 5e^{ \arctan(4/3)}$.  The principal $p$th root is $\sqrt[p]{5}e^{\frac{\arctan(4/3)}{p}i}$